# -bash: import: command not found : command not found Java Compilation Mac Terminal

Tags: java, bash, macos, terminal, compilation

I am new to programming in Java and have been working on university computers with Windows. I am a Mac user and having trouble trying to compile in terminal. These are the errors I am presented with:

```sh
Last login: Wed Feb 13 11:48:22 on ttys000
Sams-MacBook-Air:~ samsmac$ cd /Users/samsmac/Desktop/Week15 
Sams-MacBook-Air:Week15 samsmac$ javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar;. MessageBoardServerV4.java
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
-bash: //: is a directory
: command not found
-bash: //: is a directory
: No such file or directory.java
-bash: //: is a directory
-bash: port: No such file or directory
: command not found
-bash: import: command not found
: command not found
-bash: import: command not found
: command not found
-bash: import: command not found
-bash: //: is a directory
-bash: import: command not found
-bash: //: is a directory
: command not found
-bash: public: command not found
: command not found
-bash: static: command not found
-bash: private: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
-bash: MessageBoardServerV4.java: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'bash: MessageBoardServerV4.java: line 16: `        public Clock() { t = 0; }
```

This compiles and runs perfectly fine on Windows. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

On ix operating systems like OSX `;` is the command separator. Path separator is `:`.

So change to:

```
javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar:. MessageBoardServerV4.java
```